# Scoring a Likert Scale

Tags: spss

I have 12 variables with values from 0 to 3. I want to compute a total score variable (let's call it "Total score") by just the sum of the values in all these 12 variables, so then I'll be able to choose only the individuals who scored more than let's say 2.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SUM` command to compute the total across the 12 variables, and then use `SELECT IF` to select cases that have a total value above 2.

```
COMPUTE TotalScore = SUM(VAR1 to VAR12).
*If you want to select people with over 2.
SELECT IF TotalScore > 2.
```